# Accessing C struct as a C++ class

Tags: c++, g++, wrapper

Is there a workaround for [this bug in gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30298)?

Specifically, I think I am running into the bug when compiling a wrapper for  pthread_mutex_t.  The header looks like:

```
class DerivedClass: public pthread_mutex_t{
  public:
     DerivedClass() {}
     ~DerivedClass(){}
     DerivedClass someFunction(){}
};
```

The code is from a legacy system and used to compile on GCC 3.2.x but won't do on GCC 4.1.2.

... In theory I guess I could recompile everything on a back-version GCC or refactor the referencing sources to disuse the wrapper, but I want to see if there is an easier way first.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The bug is fixed in GCC 4.6.0, but if you need it now, use composition instead:

```
class DerivedClass {
  public:
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
// ...
}
```

If what you need is a class which can be casted to a `pthread_mutex_t *`, then make sure your class has no virtual functions, and put the mutex as the first element in the class; you can then convert between `DerivedClass *` and `pthread_mutex_t *` safely. Or add an `operator pthread_mutex_t *()`.

Comment: What does it matter if `pthread_mutex_t` has a variable by that name?  The library will use `pthread_mutex_t*` and find its variable, the client code will use `DerivedClass*` and find the function.  Composition is probably a better way, however you've oversimplified the requirements for a standard-layout class.

Comment: Making it a public data member is not encapsulation; surely you mean composition.

Comment: @Ben, ah, I was under the impression that you couldn't overload member variables with member functions in a derived class, but it looks like you can, in fact, do so. Hm.

Comment: In C++, new members don't overload base members with the same name, they hide them.  If you want overloading the `using` declaration is helpful.

Comment: Thanks all, will try when get back to work next week.  In the hind-sight composition would be the obvious solution, I have been thinking too much to try to avoid gcc from thinking the code is having redefinition of pthread_mutex_t.